# Laravel 5.5 "Class 'PDO' not found"

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, pdo

Here is the actual error when I open the site

[image]

Actually, I have successfully run `php artisan migrate:refresh`, and there is no error.

Already tried the following command.

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:clear

composer install
composer clearcache
composer dump-autoload
php artisan clear-compiled
```

I also checked if pdo is installed, thru `php -m` and its already installed

[image]

I'm using CentOS.

Comment: When does the error happen?

Comment: when I open the site

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What is most likely happening here is that the PDO module is enabled in the php-cli config (hence it works from command line), but is not enabled on the web server configuration file.

Comment: for me it was reverse, in my docker container, it was working fine, but in my local cli, pdo was not enabled

Answer (score 7):

I am adding all possible options which can solve the issue

```
Add use PDO; after your namespace or just before your class or at the top of your PHP file
```

As you are using centOS try the below commands

```
yum install php-pdo
yum install php-pdo_mysql

service httpd restart
```

If still its not solved check the php.ini file path to see which is being loaded in the phpinfo() output.

Sometimes there are two different PHP versions installed on a machine, one for CLI and one for the web server.

Answer (score 1):

Restart your apache, nginx, php-fpm

Answer (score 1):

1. Run `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` and find out the /path/to/php.ini
2. Open php.ini

   `sudo nano /path/to/php.ini`
3. Add these lines to enable the extensions

   ```
   extension=openssl
   extension=pdo_firebird
   extension=pdo.so
   extension=pdo_mysql
   extension=pdo_oci
   extension=pdo_odbc
   extension=pdo_pgsql
   extension=pdo_sqlite
   ```
4. Restart the server

   `sudo apachectl restart`